# Проблема с импортом библиотеки

Tags: android, gradle

Импортнул свой старый проект, в котором использовалась сторонняя библиотека для отрисовки `numberPickerDialog` в стиле material. Взята [отсюда](https://github.com/KasualBusiness/MaterialNumberPicker). В `build.gradle` изменил зависимость с `compile 'biz.kasual:materialnumberpicker:1.2.1'` на `implementation 'biz.kasual:materialnumberpicker:1.2.1'`, так как этого просила студия, но `import biz.kasual.materialnumberpicker.MaterialNumberPicker;` остался также невалидным, то есть написан серо/красным шрифтом. Основной класс `MaterialNumberPicker` не виден, портнуться не дает, но тем не менее, проект билдится, не смотря на то что весь код покрыт красным полотном и отрабатывает тоже корректно. Под android давно не писал, возможно упустил какие-то моменты? Посоветуйте, господа. Буду признателен.

[image: Can't import]

Comment: Sync, reload, invalidate cache?

Comment: @SergeMarkov пробовал, не помогает

Comment: импорт со * или конкретных классов?

Comment: @SergeMarkov со всех

Comment: Попробуйте так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48734990/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо большое! Помогло)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Если что, то можно опубликовать ответ, я помечу его верным. Ошибка нетривиальная, мало ли кто столкнется.

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, мне лень переписывать всё оттуда) Может вы сами, а мы вам плюсики? =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Аналогично=) Лень-матушка..